# How to add an image in laravel cart and show in blade template

Tags: php, laravel

CartController.php

```
public function addcart(Request $req)
{
    $id = $req->id ;
    $name = $req->name;
    $quantity = $req->quantity;
    $cost = $req->cost;
    $image = $req->image;

    Cart::add(array('id' => $id,
                    'name' => $name, 
                    'qty' => $quantity, 
                    'price' => $cost,
                    'image' => $image));

    $cart = Cart::content();

    return view('viewcart')->with('cart',$cart);
}
```

viewcart.blade.php

```
@foreach ($cart as $product)

    {{ $product->id }}
    {{ $product->name }}
    {{ $product->qty }}
    {{ $product->price }}
    {{ $product->image }}

@endforeach
```

The following work fine:

```
{{ $product->id }}
{{ $product->name }}
{{ $product->qty }}
{{ $product->price }}
```

However, below does not show anything:

```
{{ $product->image }}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the value of $product->image

Comment: $product->image=/img/img.jpg

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Check your browser console

Answer (score 2):

To display an image you have to use HTML `img` tag eg:

`<img src="{{ $product->image }}">`

P.S. You must store proper path of image in `$product->image` to display it.

Comment: Your path to image is not correct I assume, make sure `$product->image` contains an URL to the image.

Answer (score 0):

go to vendors, locate the cart package and find the cart model and modify. for example if you are using darryldecode/cart modify the "add" method as below - you can see that 'image' has been added to the validator method parameters and to calls with the method. That should work. save the file and try.

```
public function add($id, $name = null, $price = null, $quantity = null, $image = null, $slug = null, $attributes = array(), $conditions = array())
        {
            // if the first argument is an array,
            // we will need to call add again
            if (is_array($id)) {
                // the first argument is an array, now we will need to check if it is a multi dimensional
                // array, if so, we will iterate through each item and call add again
                if (Helpers::isMultiArray($id)) {
                    foreach ($id as $item) {
                        $this->add(
                            $item['id'],
                            $item['name'],
                            $item['price'],
                            $item['quantity'],
                            $item['image'],
                            $item['slug'],
                            Helpers::issetAndHasValueOrAssignDefault($item['attributes'], array()),
                            Helpers::issetAndHasValueOrAssignDefault($item['conditions'], array())
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->add(
                        $id['id'],
                        $id['name'],
                        $id['price'],
                        $id['quantity'],
                        $id['image'],
                        $id['slug'],
                        Helpers::issetAndHasValueOrAssignDefault($id['attributes'], array()),
                        Helpers::issetAndHasValueOrAssignDefault($id['conditions'], array())
                    );
                }

                return $this;
            }

            // validate data
            $item = $this->validate(array(
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $name,
                'price' => Helpers::normalizePrice($price),
                'quantity' => $quantity,
                'image' => $image,
                'slug' => $slug,
                'attributes' => new ItemAttributeCollection($attributes),
                'conditions' => $conditions,
            ));

            // get the cart
            $cart = $this->getContent();

            // if the item is already in the cart we will just update it
            if ($cart->has($id)) {

                $this->update($id, $item);
            } else {

                $this->addRow($id, $item);

            }

            return $this;
        }
```